# How to share text from the "EditText" or "Textbox" via a share button

Tags: android

I have a textbox(EditText) in my app & a button, what i want to do is that when anyone tap the button, the text written in the textbox(EditText) get copied & this text can be shared to any of the app such as - Messaging, Gmail, Ymail, etc. 
Now What i am doing is getting the text from the "EditText" & storing it into a new variable (string) say 'a' & now applying the Intent "ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE"

Here is the CODE for Intent

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"example@gmail.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "a");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, a);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share it via..."));
```

Comment: What is your problem..?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but this is how you get text from an editText

```
String mString= et.getText().toString();
```

Then put it in the share intent

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mString);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

If you want to send it as an email only, and only allow email clients to respond to the intent, it goes something like this.

```
Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
String uriText = "mailto:" + Uri.encode("mail to address") 
   + "?subject=" + Uri.encode("subject here") 
   + "&body=" + Uri.encode("body here");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);
send.setData(uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send, "Send..."));
```

This allows you to enter the subject field & mailto field...etc

Answer (score 0):

You need "createChooser" maybe:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, edittext.getText().toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "chooser title"));
```